# How to import mhx2 model programmatically?

Tags: import, makehuman

I want to import a mhx2 model into blender using a script. I know that the function is **bpy.ops.import_scene.makehuman_mhx2()** but cannot figure out what the parameters are. Could someone provide an example? Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

bpy.ops.import_scene.makehuman_mhx2(filter_glob="*.mhx2", filepath="C:\\1.mhx2", useHelpers=False, useOffset=True, useOverride=False, useCustomShapes=True, useFaceShapes=False, useFaceShapeDrivers=False, useFaceRigDrivers=True, useFacePanel=False, useRig=True, finalizeRigify=True, useRotationLimits=True, useDeflector=False, useHairDynamics=False, useHairOnProxy=False, useConservativeMasks=True, useSubsurf=False, subsurfLevels=0, subsurfRenderLevels=1, useMasks='MODIFIER', useHumanType='BOTH', mergeBodyParts=False, mergeToProxy=False, mergeMaxType='BODY', rigType='EXPORTED', genitalia='NONE', usePenisRig=False, hairType='NONE', hairColor=(0.15, 0.03, 0.005, 1))